# Reconciling apt and snap installations of dotnet

Tags: 22.04, dotnet

Having two installations of .NET:

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
$ which dotnet 
/usr/bin/dotnet
$ which dotnet-sdk.dotnet 
/snap/bin/dotnet-sdk.dotnet
```

The two installations seem independent:

```
$ dotnet --list-sdks
6.0.109 [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.109/sdk]
$ dotnet-sdk.dotnet --list-sdks
7.0.100-rc.1.22431.12 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/181/sdk]
```

I have tried to apt remove all dotnet:

```
sudo apt remove --purge dotnet-sdk-6.0
sudo apt remove --purge dotnet-runtime-6.0
sudo apt remove --purge aspnetcore*
```

but after that dotnet still points to something not installed via snap:

```bash
$ which dotnet
/usr/bin/dotnet
```

Following the symlinks:

```
/usr/bin/dotnet -> /etc/alternatives/dotnet
/etc/alternatives/dotnet -> /usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.109/dotnet
```

Since PATH has `/usr/bin/` before `/snap/bin` the non-snap version kicks in when `dotnet` is exectuted and the brute force solution would be move `/snap/bin` to the front of PATH but I'm not sure if this could have unexpected consequences.

What is best way to reconcile these? My preferred options, I think, would be to only have the snap managed installations.

Answer (score 0):

After another attempt to `sudo apt remove --purge dotnet6xxxx` I finally paid attention to `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required` section.

After `sudo apt autoremove` only the snap versions are left:

```
$ which dotnet
/snap/bin/dotnet
$ dotnet --list-sdks
7.0.100-rc.1.22431.12 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/181/sdk]
```